# How to make all links on web page call javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I load different types of content through AJAX on my website.

I have a javascript function that will decide whether to open the link in an iframe or new tab based on the URL. But the question is how do I make all links call that javascript function?

I tried:

```
<base target= processurl()/>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:
The JQUERY method works great. But it only works for one link? When I click a link the first time, it calls the function correctly. But any other links I click on after that, nothing happens.

Comment: if you have a comment for the answer, leave it under the answer by clicking "add comment"

Answer (score 4):

using jQuery < 1.7:

```
$( 'a' ).live( 'click', function( ev ){
    ev.preventDefault(); // stop normal click on link

    // do stuff
} );
```

Note that jQuery 1.7 prefers the use of `.on` instead of `.live`:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', 'a', function( ev ){
    ....
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two ways you could approach this (depending on how it fits in with your Ajax code):

1. Handle all clicks on the page with a common function that cancels the default click navigation and then subsitutes its own to load in iframe, new window, etc.
2. Process all links on the page when the page loads, setting the `target` attribute as appropriate.

So the first way:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e) {
   // stop default navigation
   e.preventDefault();

   // 'this' is the particular 'a' that was clicked
   var url = this.href;

   // process url somehow as desired to decide whether to open it
   // in new window, or iframe or to replace current page
});
```

Noting that the [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) applies from jQuery version >= 1.7, so for older jQuery use the [`.delegate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or for *really* old jQuery use the [`.live()` method](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

The second way (assumes links all exist when page is first loaded):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").each(function() {
        var url = this.href;

        // process url somehow and set the target attribute as appropriate
        // e.g. for a new window
        this.target = "_blank";
        // or for an iframe
        this.target = "nameofiframe"
        // etc.
    });
});
```

Comment: There's no difference between `live` and `delegate` in this context

Comment: @cwolves - True, but I figure the sooner I get out of the habit of using `live()` the less I'll have to worry if/when it is completely removed in a future version of jQuery. (I'm still using `delegate()` though: as it happens my current project is stuck on jQuery 1.4.4, for reasons nobody can explain though I'm not allowed to change it.)

Comment: still the same problem with method one. it works once and doesn't work again :(  what i mean is the first link i click, the iframe loads properly but after that none of the links i click work.

Comment: Are you talking about links in the newly loaded iframe not working? Does it matter which link you click first? I think you might have to provide a demo (perhaps on http://jsfiddle.net) and/or show your html.

Comment: its a popup iframe called shadow box. i want all links to open in the shadow box. so the first link i click on the main web page opens correctly with the shadow box but after I close the shadow box, none of the links in the main web page works.